# Create new DataFrame containing mean information

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the columns "Action", "Filt" and "Val" which measure the resulting error of filtering an action. I want to calculate the mean of the error for each "Action" and "Filt". Currently, I do this by iterating through each combination of "Action" and "Filt". However, I'm afraid the slicing is taking up more time than I would like.

```
import pandas as pd

in_dat = [
    ("run", "raw", 1),
    ("run", "deep", 1),
    ("jump", "raw", 2),
    ("jump", "deep", 2),
    ("run", "raw", 2),
    ("run", "deep", 2),
    ("jump", "raw", 3),
    ("jump", "deep", 3)

]


all_err = pd.DataFrame(in_dat, columns=("action", "filt", "val"))

mean_vals = []

for act in tuple(all_err.action.unique()):
    for filt in tuple(all_err.filt.unique()):
        mean_val = all_err[(all_err.action == act) & (all_err.filt == filt)].val.mean()
        mean_vals.append((act, filt, mean_val))


mean_err = pd.DataFrame(mean_vals, columns=("Action", "Filt", "Error"))
```

This gives the result of `mean_err` being:

```
  Action  Filt  Error
0    run   raw    1.5
1    run  deep    1.5
2   jump   raw    2.5
3   jump  deep    2.5
```

What's a faster way to do this with Pandas and getting a similar result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### pandas is deep

The pandas toolkit is very deep and can take a while to grok some of the basics.  In the case of your code, you are replicating the functionality in [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby).  `groupby` gathers all of the elements together with matching values in the fields indicated and then allows those elements to be worked on as a group.  In the case of:

```
for act in tuple(all_err.action.unique()):
    for filt in tuple(all_err.filt.unique()):
```

This code is referencing all values of the `action` and `filt` columns into two variables.  Then:

```
mean_val = all_err[(all_err.action == act) & (all_err.filt == filt)].val.mean()
mean_vals.append((act, filt, mean_val))
```

These lines perform a mean on the `val` column for each row that matches in the two grouped columns, and stores those results into a list.  Pandas has a *shortcut* for these sorts of operations called `groupby`.  The above four lines, plus the list initialization, can be equivalently written as:

```
all_err.groupby(['action', 'filt']).val.mean()
```

#### How?

Starting with:

```
all_err.groupby(['action', 'filt'])
```

produces a `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy`.  This object instance understands how to iterate over the dataframe a group at a time, allowing access to these groups in various ways.  So then,

```
all_err.groupby(['action', 'filt']).val
```

selects the `val` column to work against, and finally,

```
all_err.groupby(['action', 'filt']).val.mean()
```

asks for the mean value of that column.

#### Results:

```
mean_err = all_err.groupby(['action', 'filt']).val.mean()
print(mean_err)

  Action  Filt  Error
0    run   raw    1.5
1    run  deep    1.5
2   jump   raw    2.5
3   jump  deep    2.5
```